# problem when i run this command "npm install expo-cli --global"

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, global, expo

That is what I got when I run `npm install expo-cli --global`

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-5eWZW492TvNODXB4K4LsUMBQXjmLXz1LfuIeCkBCA4RCwyX8dSU2/g1g/1LbEYl/yQnQ8MhCNeDzPtp+nwRDiQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-5eWZW492TvNODXB4K4LsUMBQXjmLXz1LfuIeCkBCA4RCwyX8dSU2/g1g/1LbEYl/yQnQ8MhCNeDzPtp+nwRDiQ== but got sha512-R85gjoiz3lDG1MlV8jpzoo0Oy5JRlDpoRsvZU6hTSPAOFG+tzPAVz70kmwVpBV0cvMVPRXZXaiSaoYJU0sr1dA==. (4950409 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Think\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-04T17_06_08_784Z-debug.log
```

[image: command output]

Comment: Are you using the latest npm version (6.14.4)?

Comment: yes its it works now i just run as an administrator so it works now thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 0):

-> run npm cache clean --force

-> then run npm i -g expo-cli